# Adding the ability for a user to input into this VBA script without going into the developer tab?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The code below carries out a find and replace across multiple documents, but to change the words used, one needs to go into the VBA code its self.  I want to add the ability for a user to do this in microsoft word, using a message box or something similar? How would the code be changed to do this?

```
    Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim MyDialog As FileDialog, GetStr(1 To 100) As String '100 files is the maximum applying this code
  Title = "InputBox Demo"    ' Set title.
  On Error Resume Next
  Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  With MyDialog
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All WORD File ", "*.docx", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    i = 1
    If .Show = -1 Then
      For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
        GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
        i = i + 1
      Next
      i = i - 1
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For j = 1 To i Step 1
      Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=GetStr(j), Visible:=True)
      Windows(GetStr(j)).Activate
      Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
      Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
      With Selection.Find
        .Text = InputBox( _
    "Type the word you want to find", _
    "Choose the word to find", _
    "Type the word here") 'Find What
        .Replacement.Text = InputBox( _
    "Type the word you want to replace", _
    "Choose the word to replace", _
    "Type the word here") 'Replace With
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
      End With
      Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      Application.Run macroname:="NEWMACROS"
      ActiveDocument.Save
      ActiveWindow.Close
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End With
  MsgBox "operation end, please view", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Alternatively this could be done in excel, but the code doesn't work in excel - not sure why, there's a

> compile error

I'm not sure how to alter the code to make it workable in excel but it may be easier so you could make the user input of 'find' and 'replace' from a cell.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it reasonable to have a message box appear and ask the user for their list of words at runtime? You could also provide default values.

Comment: You can enter the VBA editor with ALT-F11 but it's a bad idea to let the users change the code.

Comment: There is a compile error in Excel because Excel doesnt know what `wdReplaceAll` is without a Word library reference.

Comment: You can use `InputBox` to let the user enter a variable's value.

Comment: Besides what @braX suggests, you could also provide a UserForm to get user input. That's more code than an InputBox, but it could be more user-friendly and perhaps simpler to pick up the individual terms (user clicks for each term, instead of a list separated by some character that you have to separate). Or the user could supply the terms in a text file or another Word document. Lots of possibilities, really...

Comment: Thanks guys really appreciate the help.  I have used the inputbox function where the "search" and "find" fields are, and it correctly brings up the box for user input, but it brings it up for every single document that the user selects.  I just want the user input in the input boxes for find and replace to apply to all documents.  Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: To clarify, the new code is in the post

Comment: Before you enter the loop `For j = 1 To i Step 1`, get the two inputbox results and put them in string variables:
`Dim findWhat as string`
`findWhat = InputBox(...)`
Do the same for replaceWith and then use those variables inside the For loop.